# Made some work - Need feedback

Tags: feedback, criticism

I keep doing sound design exercises by re-designing visuals found around the web. Last time it was rockets and marsmachine, so this time i wanted to try something mystic and fragile to recreate.

http://vimeo.com/17823258

Well, without any words, check out my video if you will have a time and possibly give me your criticism about motion, sounds together, anything you will find to mention there.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Watched it once, first impressions:

1. Great job! Love the clarity and "sparkle", nice detail and use of all frequencies.
2. The musical pad felt a little creepy in the first 1/3, but that's not a bad thing…made me wonder what was coming next.
3. Great sounds for the star flybys, very effective and identifiable.

Keep up the creative work!

Answer (score 1):

I liked it. I want to hear it in 5.1!

My initial question was if you synthesized those sounds, but then I figured that was a dumb question. How did you synthesize the wind whips - was it a sound you recorded then edited in place/sync, or sound that you synthesized/composed to picture?

Comment: Thanks!
There is a mixture of several layers. For the lights I used white noise shaped with LPF and BPF (two layers) + reverb and flanger + some doppler transitions + fireworks (fountain). 

Comment: @Pretaeperon What is BPF and LPF? Low Pass Filter and Bass Pass Filter...?

Comment: yep, I thoght its pretty common abbreviation.  BPF is Band pass Filter.

Comment: Niiiiiice - the technique turned out well.

Answer (score 1):

Nice work! I thought it sounded great and was very polished. I liked the detail in the sounds, and they were very cohesive with the visuals.

My only constructive criticism would be that the light trails/wooshes do sound quite synthesized, and I think they could be improved by a more organic treatment - perhaps layering in a more natural element, or applying some processing with EQ, harmonic enhancement or a touch of reverb.

Comment: yeah, i am working on that, but im novice, it will take some time to come up with that... 

Comment: you could try to input some sub frequencies in some parts (around 50hz) or a better way is to find your basic frequency and input its sub-harmonic freqs

Answer (score 1):

great work!

my only suggestion is to add some sub frequencies cause i found bottom end to be a little empty!

either way! great work! what did you use to make the basic "theme" sound?

Comment: I used modified reaktor instrument - SpaceDrone mod by Richard Devine and Antonio Blanca + a bit of spectrasonics atmosphere's sounds, then made some mutations between them using Sound Forge Acoustic mirror - which is my favorite tool for the soundscapes.

Answer (score 1):

I always think it's such a great exercise to take videos off the web and recreate your own sound design to them. Overall I think you did great job with the piece. The mood ambience gives couldn't have been better for this. It has a mysterious sort of feel to it. Like Nikos mentioned I would add a little bit more low end to give the sparking lights a bit more heft when they're whizzing by.

Answer (score 1):

very nice work.  very clean and detailed.

Loved the gritty initial texture of the sparks, and the cleaner resolution of the tails.  I think they work very well together.

panning and sync were all perfect.

I also like the background textures, though I think I'd like to hear some wood or forest in addition to the pad, though that's entirely a stylistic thing.

The only critique I have is when the "five" breaks up at :19 I'd like it to tie in more with the established spark sounds and maybe have another low end poof-y event there.  that's pretty minor though, very nice work.

Answer (score 0):

added several improvements based on your suggestions guys - now it sounds more serious and heavy... but still transparent enough. 
it is kind of 'cinematic' sound design now, especially compaired to the original which is:

http://vimeo.com/10896699

My second version is still under that link.

BTW - I am prepairing my portfolio for the admission at the university, and hoping to make several works containing this one...